# How to return as a string in recursive?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm doing decimal to binary using recursion method.
However, I was unable to convert it to string using the code below.
Any help? <3

```
def to_binary(d):
  if d == 0:
    return str(0)
  else:
    return str(d % 2 + 10 * to_binary(int(d // 2)))

result = to_binary(nums)
print("Result: " + result)
```

It's always giving errors:

- unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

*Updated*

Comment: What is the issue? Does it give an error? If so, please post its *full text*. Give us some sample input, expected output, and the actual output, if any. You need to describe *why* you need help, not just say that you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Likely the formula in the last line is wrong.

Your function should return a string. But then the last line would try to add and multiply a number with a string - what result do you expect?

I suggest this last line:

```
return to_binary(int(d // 2))) + str(d % 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your last line has a mistake.for example consider 3 converts to binary.it must be `to_binary(3//2) = to_binary(1) + 3%2=1`

```
def to_binary(d):
  if d == 0:
    return str(0)
  elif(d==1):
     return str(1)
  else:
    return str(to_binary(d // 2)+str(d%2))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, now i understand where did I go wrong!
I'll need to return both string of the function and "d % 2".
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well bro the error is pretty straight forward. Here: `return str(d % 2 + 10 * to_binary(int(d // 2)))` you call `to_binary`, which returns a String, but then try to add it with a number `d % 2`.

Simply change that line to: `return str(d % 2 + 10 * int(to_binary(int(d // 2))))`. This should solve your error.